# Given $f(z)=z^2+c$. Prove that $|z|>|c|+1$ implies $|f(z)|>|z|$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, complex-dynamics

Consider the quadratic function $f(z)=z^2+c$. If $|z|>|c|+1$, show that $|f(z)|>|z|$.

Edit: This is not a homework problem. I found this in my textbook.

Comment: Don't you just get that $|z|\geq 1 $, so that , for $=re^{i\theta}$ , $|f(re^{i\theta})|=|re^{i\theta}|\geq |r^2|>r$ for $r>1$?

Comment: How did you get the first equality?

Comment: Since $|z|>|c|+1$, it implies that $|z|>1$ since $|c|>0$

Comment: @user44322: does that work for you?

Comment: I meant $|f(reiθ)|=|reiθ|$

Comment: That is a representative quality of a complex number

Comment: $f(z)=z^2+c$. If $z=re^{i\theta}$ why is $r^2e^{2i\theta}+c=re^{i\theta}$?

Comment: I don't understand why my question is considered as off topic.

Comment: I believe this is the corrected version. $|f(re^{i\theta})|=|r^2e^{2i\theta}|\geq |r^2|>r$

Comment: Thís is just the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two preliminary inequalities:

- By the triangular inequality, $z^2=f(z)-c$ implies $|z|^2\leqslant|f(z)|+|c|$.
- If $|z|\gt|c|+1$, then $|z|^2-|z|=|z|(|z|-1)\gt(|c|+1)|c|=|c|^2+|c|$.

These two inequalities together yield $|f(z)|-|z|\geqslant|z|^2-|z|-|c|\gt|c|^2\geqslant0$ hence $|f(z)|\gt|z|$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is based on the algorithms used to make pictures of Julia sets.  If the sequence $(x,f(x),f(f(x)), \dots )$ ever enters the region $|z| > R_f$ it will never return, and will be drawn toward the point at infinity ($|z|$ will get larger and larger, without bound), for a value of $R_f$ that depends on $f$ but not $z$.  The colors of points in the thermal plots are assigned based on the number of iterations for a point to enter the region, or some subset $|z| > M_f > R_f$ for which $M_f$ is easier to compute explicitly in terms of $f$.

$M_{z^2+c} =|c|+1$ is enough but its only purpose is to have a clean bound that excludes $z$ from the Julia set.  The minimum sufficient $R_f$ is the larger solution of $R^2 - |c| = R$, which is close to $\sqrt{|c|}$.  The extreme case is when $|z|=R$ and the vector of the complex number $z^2$ points in the opposite direction to $c$.